# Incremento en una funcion no todas

Tags: javascript

tengo muchos **onclick** dentro de un **foreach**, cada uno llama a una function. la idea es que haga un incremento de los clicks. pero solo en esa function no en las otras. alguna solución

```
var inputCantAdd__Item = 1;
function inputCantAdd(th){

var p = th.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0];
var price = Number(p.getAttribute('data-price'));

var single_total = inputCantAdd__Item * price;
th.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].value = inputCantAdd__Item;
inputCantAdd__Item++;


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack overflow. Te sugiero que leas el apartado sobre como formular preguntas [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para no plantear preguntas tan abiertas. Por favor, publica tu código para ver en dónde hay errores pues tu pregunta es muy abierta.

Comment: actualizado la informacion

Comment: No se ve la parte del foreach ni de los onClick.